# How can I check numbers with comparison operators in each divided chunk? With Python

Tags: python, comparison, chunks

I have the following output:

```
[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 4, 4], [4, 5, 1], [5, 5, 5], [2, 4, 3], [5, 5, 1], [4, 5, 4], [4, 5, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 5], [2, 2, 2], [3, 5, 3], [2, 2, 2], [1, 3, 1], [3, 3, 2], [2, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [3, 5, 3].
```

How can I test with python each chunk using the following formula:

- First number of chunk less than or equal third number of chunk greater than or equal second number of chunk?

  So that I can test for example the first chunk and if the third number is in the range of the first and the second (**E.g.** number 5 is the 3rd number, and the 1st number is number 2 and the 2nd number is number 8. **i.e.** number 5 is in the range between 2 to 8.) I can print `True` or `False`

Comment: `[i[2] in range(i[0], i[1]+1) for i in [your-input-of-lists-goes-here]]`

Comment: @GhostOps that hurts my eyes....

Comment: i know, but the OP doesn't mention that its a single array or input, so thats why i did that, sry for that

Comment: Oh it's fair.  Kind of thing you might find in code deployed by my uni, too ;)

Comment: @GhostOps - The `True` and `False` is unncessary. `i[2] in range(i[0], i[1]+1))` already returns boolean values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison is more efficient than using `in range(...)`

```
all([start <= num and num <= end for start, end, num in lst])
```

#### Performance testing

**Input:**

```
lst = [[i, i+1, i+1] for i in range(1000)]
```

**With `in range(...)`:**

Code:

```
%timeit [l[-1] in range(l[0], l[1]+1) for l in lst]
print(all([l[-1] in range(l[0], l[1]+1) for l in lst]))
```

Output:

```
1.22 ms ± 161 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
True
```

**With comparison**

Code:

```
%timeit [start <= num and num <= end for start, end, num in lst ]
print(all([start <= num and num <= end for start, end, num in lst ]))
```

Output:

```
258 µs ± 29.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range):

```
lst = [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 4, 4], [4, 5, 1], [5, 5, 5], [2, 4, 3], [5, 5, 1], [4, 5, 4], [4, 5, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 5], [2, 2, 2], [3, 5, 3], [2, 2, 2], [1, 3, 1], [3, 3, 2], [2, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [3, 5, 3]

>>> [l[-1] in range(l[0], l[1]+1) for l in lst]
[True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, 
 True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True]
```

Or [`comparisons`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

```
>>> [l[0]<=l[1]<=l[-1] for l in lst]
[True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True,
 True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True]
```